# How to register resource with javax.ws.rs.core.Applicaiton in spring-boot-starter-jersey powered REST application

Tags: spring-boot, jersey, jax-rs

In my spring boot application (powered by spring-boot-starter-jersey):

I can easily make a resource config (jersey way but not jaxrs way) like this:

```
@Configuration
@ApplicationPath("/sample")
public class SampleResourceConfig extends ResourceConfig {
```

And I just want to try with javax.ws.rs.core.Applicaiton:

```
    @Configuration
    @ApplicationPath("/sample")
    public class SampleResourceConfig extends javax.ws.rs.core.Applicaiton{

  public Set<Class<?>> getClasses() {
    Set<Class<?>> classes = new HashSet<Class<?>>();
    classes.add(SampleResource.class);
    return classes;
  }
```

But no lucky, it does not work.

Did I miss something?

Thanks

Leon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It won't work as the [Spring Boot auto-configuration](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jersey/JerseyAutoConfiguration.html) is made specifically to look for a [bean of type `ResourceConfig`](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v1.5.8.RELEASE/spring-boot-autoconfigure/src/main/java/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/jersey/JerseyAutoConfiguration.java#L102), not `Application`. If you want to use `Application`, you can't use the auto-configuration. You'll need to just create the JAX-RS servlet yourself and register it with a Spring Boot `ServletRegistratiobBean`, similar to what you'll see in the source code I linked to.

Comment: ah, got it! Thanks a lot for the quick response!